# How to correctly say IF below 0 then print

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to print the values and they print  just fine. but as soon as insert an if statement the server gives out WSOD

Can someone please have a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I need to print the values only if field_val_nominal is below Zero.

```
<?php 
 $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
 $field_val_nominal = $node_wrapper->field_price_change_nominal_comp->value();
 $field_val_percent = $node_wrapper->field_price_change_percent_comp->value();

if ($field_val_nominal < 0 && $field_val_nominal != 0)  : print render($field_val_nominal) . t('(') . render($field_val_percent) . t('%)') ;
     ?>
```

I've been banging my head against this problem for a while. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove the : before the print statement

Comment: The second part of your `if()` statement is redundant. if x is less than zero x will never equal zero.

Comment: Thanks. I've taken both advices into account and now have
if ($field_val_nominal < 0) print render($field_val_nominal) . t('(') . render($field_val_percent) . t('%)') ;

but I still get WSOD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use curly brackets instead of a colon.  And your "if" conditions can be shortened into a single condition, like this:

```
<?php 
 $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
 $field_val_nominal = $node_wrapper->field_price_change_nominal_comp->value();
 $field_val_percent = $node_wrapper->field_price_change_percent_comp->value();

if ($field_val_nominal < 0)
    {
    print render ($field_val_nominal) . t('(') . render($field_val_percent) . t('%)') ;
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  The curly brackets did the trick.  I still get confused when to use colon and when the curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo??   The colon doesn't belong in your if statement.

```
<?php 
 $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
 $field_val_nominal = $node_wrapper->field_price_change_nominal_comp->value();
 $field_val_percent = $node_wrapper->field_price_change_percent_comp->value();

if ($field_val_nominal < 0)
     print render($field_val_nominal) . t('(') . render($field_val_percent) . t('%)') ;
?>
```